# Unable to locate package schroot

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install schroot on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an ARM64 machine so that I can run 32-bit programs.

However when I type

```
sudo apt get install schroot
```

I get

```
Unable to locate package schroot
```

I am guessing this is due to some missing repository? How would I find out what repository schroot is in?

My background with Linux is intermediate - I can generally get a Linux setup up and working, but I don't know finer details on specifics like package repositories and such.

Comment: Could you give the output of `apt-cache policy`?
The `schroot` package is available in the main `ubuntu-ports` repository:
`deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic main`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follow:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main
```

then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install schroot
```